# Highcharts - programmatically "flip" (reverse) Y Axis

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

All,

I'm using Highcharts in a web app I'm working on. One of the requirements is that users should be able to click a button and "flip" or reverse the Y axis.

In other words - when the user clicks a button - the y Axis values should flip from:

```
highest at the top / lowest at the bottom
```

to

```
lowest at the top / highest at the bottom
```

When you first create the chart - this is possible using the "reversed" property of the y Axis:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.reversed

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZgVNS/

However - if I attempt to do this programmatically with JavaScript using the options object (e.g., on a button click), it doesn't seem to work:

```
chart.options.yAxis.reversed = !chart.options.yAxis.reversed;
chart.redraw();
```

Here's a jsfiddle I set up to test: http://jsfiddle.net/4JZxS/6/

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `@oftopic`: It's my jsfiddle or it's not showing loaded code ?

Comment: @RicardoLohmann Mine is not working at Chrome. In firefox I can see the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Axis.update() method:

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            reversed: false
        },
        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
   });

   var reversed = chart.options.yAxis.reversed;

   // the button action
   $('#button').click(function () {

       chart.yAxis[0].update({
           reversed: !reversed
       });  

       reversed = !reversed;
   });
});
```

Here's the updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4JZxS/15/

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible.

My advice is to destroy the chart using `chart.destroy()` and create the new one with the reversed property, like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4JZxS/8/)